using Selenium on R for web scraping of dynamic content
I am quite new on R and am currently trying to do web scrapping on the ISO website. I have trouble using Selenium : it does not seem to be compatible with my chrome version, despite me trying to install another version of the latter. I have seen several people with a problem close to mine but their solution doesn't seem to work for me.
Here is my project : I want to store in an R dataframe the title of the page results that appear when i search for "packaging" on the ISO website, in the "standards" section. I want my code to, for each result, take the name of the norm, the number, open the link, take the number of pages of the norm as well as the date of publication. My current code only tries to extract ISO number (the code number) and titles of the results, not click on the results to open the page associated with each result, and take the number of pages and date of publication.
 #### WEB SCRAPPING NORMES ISO ####

  library(dplyr)

  ## 1. I get the html code of the first page of results to understand the structure of the html
  # code. I should probably do the same for the first page that I can open by clicking on the 
  # first result.

  library(rvest)
  library(xml2)
  url <- "https://www.iso.org/search.html? PROD_isoorg_en%5Bquery%5D=packaging&PROD_isoorg_en%5Bmenu%5D%5Bfacet%5D=standard"
  page <- read_html(url)
  html_content <- as.character(page)
  cat(html_content)
  html_structure <- xml_structure(page)

 ## 2. I get the html code from each the 24 pages of results (there are 470 results in total)

 library(rvest)
 library(purrr)
  base_url <- "https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%5Bquery%5D=packaging&PROD_isoorg_en%5Bmenu%5D%5Bfacet%5D=standard&page="
   extract_html <- function(page_number) {
   url <- paste0(base_url, page_number)
   page <- read_html(url)
    html_content <- as.character(page)
    return(html_content)
   }
  num_pages <- 24  # 470 résultats/ 20 results per page = 23.5
    html_contents <- map(1:num_pages, extract_html)


   ## package RSelenium to automate web browser interactions, such as clicking on elements,    filling out forms, and scrolling. 
    # RSelenium simulates user behavior, enabling you to access dynamically loaded content.


  # load packages
  library(RSelenium)
  library(netstat)

  # set system version to use english language
  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")


   # start the server, using a random port to ensure it's not 
   already used
   rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',verbose = 
   FALSE, port = free_port(random = T), chromever = NULL)


   # create a client object
   remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

   # open a browser
   remDr$open()

   # Initialize an empty data frame to store results
   standards_df <- data.frame(Title = character(), Number = 
   character(), PageCount = integer(), PublicationDate = 
   character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # navigate to the webpage
  remDr$navigate("https://www.iso.org/search.html?PROD_isoorg_en%5Bquery%5D=packaging&PROD_isoorg_en%5Bmenu%5D%5Bfacet%5D=standard&page=")


  # Wait for the page to load
  Sys.sleep(5) 

  # Extract titles, numbers, and links 
   # pb here : length of "titles" is only 1. My CSS selector 
    doesn't enable to get every 473 results

  titles <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', 
  'div.card:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > 
   br:nth-child(2)')
   codes <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 
  'div.card:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > 
   a:nth-child(1)')
   links <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', 
   'div.card:nth-child(2)')


   for(i in seq_along(titles)) {
      title <- titles[[i]]$getElementText()[[1]]
     link <- links[[i]]$getElementAttribute("href")[[1]]

    # Navigate to the standard's page
    remDr$navigate(link)

    # Wait for the standard's page to load
    Sys.sleep(5) # Adjust time as needed

     # Extract page count and publication date 
     pageCount <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 
     '.refine > li:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)')$getElementText()[[1]]
     publicationDate <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 
   '#publicationDate > span:nth-child(2)')$getElementText()[[1]]

     # Append the information to the data frame
     standards_df <- rbind(standards_df, data.frame(Title = title, 
    Number = NA, PageCount = pageCount, PublicationDate = 
    publicationDate, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }

  # View the collected data
  print(standards_df)

I get "subscript out of bounds" as a result, because there is only one element in my "titles", "links", etc, as the CSS selector chosen gives a single result and not each one of them.
I would welcome any help to enable me to solve my problem ! It seems there is only one element in "titles", as i do not know how to indicate to R the html structure of my pages in order for selenium to scrap the relevant information in every result and not only one.
Thanks in advance !
